# How to build a statistic model to determine if an update of web site content boosted sales, considering sales have natural growth

Tags: data-science

The data available includes ERP data for real order quantity and revenue, as well as adobe online analytics data for addin cart and online revenue.

It was asked to determine if an update of content will impact sales, so we have some proof to roll out similar update to all contents. However, the sales by nature will increase. How do we build a model to exclude natual increase sales and provide a statistical proof of increase/decrease by the update?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

If I got this right, I come up with two possible solutions:

1. if the natural grownth is predictable, you should be able to clean it out by approximating. for instance if you have 2% monthly steady sales growth (this can easyly be extracted from the ERP), you can roughly substract them from the results of the updated site. the approach details greatly depend on how presice you wish the model to be
2. perform A/B site testing. in this case you'll get the real figures. this requires to involve your web team

Comment: Thanks Igor! 1. The growth is seasonal so that applying a steady growth will give give bias. I'd like to build a statistical model, so that trend, seasonality, and randomization will take into account. But I'm not sure how to start...2. We have many other channels for example, taking order by customer service phone call, EDI. Customers may look at the content update but go ahead to non ecommerce channel to make purchase. A/B testing only cover a small portion of sales.

Comment: I alwas try to start from the simple things. 

1. I would analize sales curve in a descrete way: take say 3-5 years and see MoM, QoQ, YoY growths to find patterns that you can further use in your model. 
2. Site A/B testing could be considered as a sample study in your case. pretty sure that you can then safely approximate the results on other channels.

Sorry, if I'm not too specific. I'm new to the community.

Comment: Got it. I used to MoM and YoY with t.test plus QQplot on the percentage of changes, so that it is normalized. But the result is not significant. Thanks for suggestion, I'm also new to this, and keep getting new challenges.